# NSCollectionView - dragging shows a "hole" - want it to look lke the Finder

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I have an NSCollectionView. When I drag items (around the view, or outside of the view), I get the right appearance, but the cell is empty while the dragging occurs (see animated GIF below). The desired behavior is to be like the Finder - that is, the icon should remain in place and the dragged image appears in addition to it.

I have tried a variety of things to no avail. For example, I tried setting the drag operation to Copy in sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext. Can't remember the other ones - they failed so I deleted the experiments. When the drag completes, everything updates properly, but during the drag it looks wrong.

Is there a (hopefully easy) way to get NSCollectionView to act more like the Finder when dragging? Thanks.

[[image: The current behavior - not desired[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be essentially the same question as [Prevent NSCollectionView 'lifting' an item during drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467265/prevent-nscollectionview-lifting-an-item-during-drag/59893117#59893117)

My initial solution was to use a custom view for the collection view item. In my subclass I override `setHidden:` to prevent the collection view from hiding my item view while the item is being dragged. This had some undesirable side-effects. It appears that NSCollectionView also hides item views when changing the layout.

The next idea (so far) works fine in my application. I un-hide the item views when dragging starts.

```
@interface HGImagesCollectionViewDelegate : NSObject <NSCollectionViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation HGImagesCollectionViewDelegate

- (void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView
       draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session
      willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint
  forItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSSet<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths
{
    //  Prevent item from being hidden (creating a hole in the grid) while being dragged
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        [[[collectionView itemAtIndexPath:indexPath] view] setHidden:NO];
    }

    // …

}  

@end
```

Comment: Thanks - I just tried that and it seems to cause some unexpected behaviors (for example, most of the time, I cannot drag at any all more, and selection logic is misbehaving). Since your change is so simple, it's probably an interaction between this change and the overall complexity of my grid. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: I have updated my post with a version of the code that avoids the side-effect I had since run into.

Comment: Yes, this new implementation is working for me as well. Thank you!