# Prevent NSCollectionView 'lifting' an item during drag

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscollectionview

I understand how to get drag and drop working for `NSCollectionView` but I can't seem to stop it 'lifting' the items off the view.

My current solution is to *not* implement

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, pasteboardWriterForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSPasteboardWriting?
```

from `NSCollectionViewDelegate` to ensure that

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, draggingImageForItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>, with event: NSEvent, offset dragImageOffset: NSPointPointer) -> NSImage
```

*IS* called, where I can provide my own dragging images. However, these do not flock or provide the icon showing how many items are being dragged.

The problem is that when I implement the former method, nothing I seem to do (including overriding the NSCollectionViewItem's `draggingImageComponents`) seems to prevent the drag 'lifting' the item off the collection view, leaving behind an empty space.

Dragging images in Photos.app and files in Finder.app (icon view) do not lift the item so hopefully this is possible.

Comment: lldb + hopper shows it is a custom implementation of dragging https://imgur.com/a/BSBqOUz

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for investigating this. I take it this means I can't do something similar with public APIs?

Comment: I was checking Preview.app which has PVSidebarThumbnailController where you can do the same. It only uses public functions. So yes it's possible with public. Use Hopperapp to look inside. Also lldb to set breakpoints (-n or -a). Also set flag to debug types for items in pasteboard (Preview) using  po [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(4) forKey:@"NSDragManagerLogLevel"]. It takes too much time to replicate the feature. It shouldn't be hard to look at Apple's pseudocode in hopper to understand what is going on. https://imgur.com/a/15VCVtI (Photos.app pasteboarditems)

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: No. In the end, I made my own stack of selected items.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be essentially the same question as [NSCollectionView - dragging shows a “hole” - want it to look like the Finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467265/prevent-nscollectionview-lifting-an-item-during-drag/59893117#59893117)

My initial solution was to use a custom view for the collection view item. In my subclass I override `setHidden:` to prevent the collection view from hiding my item view while the item is being dragged. This had some undesirable side-effects. It appears that NSCollectionView also hides item views when changing the layout.

The next idea (so far) works fine in my application. I un-hide the item views when dragging starts.

```
@interface HGImagesCollectionViewDelegate : NSObject <NSCollectionViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation HGImagesCollectionViewDelegate

- (void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView
       draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session
      willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint
  forItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSSet<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths
{
    //  Prevent item from being hidden (creating a hole in the grid) while being dragged
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        [[[collectionView itemAtIndexPath:indexPath] view] setHidden:NO];
    }

    // …

}  

@end
```